# How to ungzip JSON response using zlib

Tags: json, node.js, http, zlib

I tried sending JSON response with the following code but it gives me an error saying

```
console.log(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(data);
TypeError: Cannot call method 'pipe' of undefined
```

My code:

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
  data += chunk;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(res.headers['content-encoding']);
  var output;

  switch (res.headers['content-encoding']) {
    // or, just use zlib.createUnzip() to handle both cases
    case 'gzip':
      console.log(data);
      console.log(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(data);
    break;

    case 'deflate':
      console.log(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(data);
    break;

    default:
      console.log(data);
    break;
  }
});
```

Any help regarding this will be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log()` returns nothing (undefined). You're trying to call method pipe on `console.log`'s returned value

I guess you need this `console.log(zlib.createGunzip().pipe(data));`

Comment: Now I am getting the error 
stream.js:52
  dest.on('drain', ondrain);
TypeError: Object

Comment: I think it's a more specific issue. I can't help you because this error may be caused by your data or zlib... your question was about `TypeError: Cannot call method 'pipe' of undefined` <--this error and I answered it :)